# IQueryable does not contain a definition for Count or OrderBy .. Can't figure out why

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables

Brand new to C#, ASP.NET Core and web development in general.  I'm trying to implement a generic method that I can reuse with the JQuery DataGrid. The method is as follows:

```
protected String ItemsToJson(IQueryable items, List<String> columnNames, String sort, String order, Int32 limit, Int32 offset)
        {
            try
            {
                Int32 count = items.Count();
                String sortExpression = "";

                if (sort != null && sort.Length > 0)
                    sortExpression += String.Format("{0} {1}", sort, order);

                if (limit == 0)
                    limit = count;

                var result = new
                {
                    total = count,
                    rows = items.OrderBy(sortExpression).Skip(offset).Take(limit).Select("new (" + String.Join(",", columnNames) + ")")
                };

                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings() { MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

The line reading Int32 count = items.Count(); returns the following error:

'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no accessible extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The line reading rows = Items.OrderBy(sortExpression)..... returns the following error:

'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no accessible extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have a using for System.Linq. Any thoughts? It's driving me crazy!

Thanks bunch.

--- Val

Comment: I think you need to provide us with the code that calls this method.
If you want to get the count of the collection, you need to materialize IQueryable to a collection of a certain class  `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Hi this isn't a runtime error.  I can't compile the code because of these two errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the type of item provided by the `IQueryable items`?

The Count method is available against `IQueryable<T>`, meaning if you change the incoming parameter to `IQueryable<SomeType> items`, you should be able to access it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1

> The `IQueryable` interface is intended for implementation by query
>   providers. It is only supposed to be implemented by providers that
>   also implement `IQueryable<T>`. If the provider does not also implement
>   `IQueryable<T>`, the standard query operators cannot be used on the
>   provider's data source.

Comment: Hi Adam.  The code won't compiled because of the two errors. It's not a runtime error.

Comment: Yes, that's specifically what I'm referring to. If you update your method's parameter to reference an IQueryable<T> listing a particular type for T, the queryable methods should become available: `protected String ItemsToJson(IQueryable<TheTypeOfItem> items, ...`

Comment: Got it!  Thanks a bunch Adam.

Answer (score 1):

Add package:

System.Linq.Dynamic.Core